# WSO2 ESB API - how to handle array in url parameter

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have an endpoint like this:
http://endpoint/getResult?sid=1&sid=2&sid=3...

I want to create a REST API like this, route the request to the Endpoint:
http://esb/getResult?sid=1,2,3

How can I achieve this using WSO2 ESB? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try a Java script mediator and take sid into the new String

After you can use a function split with delimiter “,”

Comment: Thanks. Can you specify how can i set multiple sid on the target endpoint?